# fadeOut current element fadeIn next element and reverse

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need some help with this one. I have a div which contains a lot of images:

```
<a href="#" id="trigger_next">Next</a>
<a href="#" id="trigger_prev">Prev</a>

<div id="image_wrapper">
  <img id="image1" class="images" src="image1.jpg"/>
  <img id="image2" class="images" style="display: none;" src="image2.jpg"/>
  <img id="image3" class="images" style="display: none;" src="image3.jpg"/>
  <img id="image4" class="images" style="display: none;" src="image4.jpg"/>
  <img id="image5" class="images" style="display: none;" src="image5.jpg"/>
  <img id="image6" class="images" style="display: none;" src="image6.jpg"/>
</div>
```

and what I'm searching for is a method which does something with the `next` or `previous` element of the same type. For example:

```
$('#trigger_next').click(function() {
  $(current_image).fadeOut();
  $(next_image).fadeIn();
});
```

What would be the best way to find out current and next image and put it in a working function.

Thanks

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/z27wT/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**in CSS**

```
  .images{
    display:none;
    }
```

**in JS**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#image_wrapper").find("img:first").show();

//for next section

$('#next').click(function() {
var visible=$("#image_wrapper img:visible"); //select visible image then do action
    visible.fadeOut();
    visible.next().fadeIn();
        });

//for previous section
 $('#previousid').click(function() {
   var visible=$("#image_wrapper img:visible");
    visible.fadeOut();
    visible.prev().fadeIn();
     });

});
```

reference **[prev()](https://api.jquery.com/prev/)** and **[next()](https://api.jquery.com/next/)**

Comment: and for previous? And isn't it like that in your case `$('#next');` would fadeOut?

Comment: when I make a `.click()` on `#next` and refer then with `$(this)` it does fade out the `#next` not the current image which is shown.